# React Native save change switch with Async Storage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, switch-statement, asyncstorage

Im new in React Native, I have a problem with Switch, I want to save changes, dark mode and Switch, when I turn off the app and come back my changes should be saved. When I close the app, my switch came back to first position and dark mode does not work. I know that Im doing something wrong, but I did not mobile app and this is my first time and I dont know how to use AsyncStorage in this App to work this. Can somebody help me solve this problem?

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const DarkModeContext = createContext();

export default function DarkModeContextProvider(props) {
  const [switchMode, setSwitchMode] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let switch1 = switchMode;
    AsyncStorage.setItem('switch1', JSON.stringify(switch1));
  });

  const SwitchThis = () => {
    setSwitchMode(!switchMode);
  };

  return (
    <DarkModeContext.Provider
      value={{
        switchMode,
        SwitchThis
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </DarkModeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and next component:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Text, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { List } from 'react-native-paper';
import BackgroundImage from './BackgroundImage';
import Clock from './Clock';
import TabIcon from './TabIcon';
import AddButton from './AddButton';
import { DarkModeContext } from './app-context';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const { switchMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

  displayData = async () => {
    try {
      let switch1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('switch1', function (err, switch1) {
        JSON.parse(switch1)
      }
)
      return switch1
    }
    catch (error) {
      return error
    }
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: !switchMode ? 'white' : '#353535'
      }}
    >
      <BackgroundImage fabButton={<AddButton/>}>
        <Clock />
      </BackgroundImage>
      <ScrollView>
        <List.Section>
          <List.Subheader style={{ color: !switchMode ? 'black' : 'white' }}>
            Task List
          </List.Subheader>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={displayData}>
            <Text>Click displayData</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity> 
        </List.Section>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: what is the version of react native?

Comment: In HomeScreen, call AsyncStorage and under useEffect use useState to set dark mode variable.

ComponentDidMount should trigger AsyncStorage.

Comment: As I can see the issue is you are not setting dark mode variable on HomeScreen load.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing AsyncStorage from 'react-native' which is deprecated
use `@react-native-community/react-native-async-storage`

`npm i @react-native-community/react-native-async-storage`

And on your home screen you are not calling the function displayData() so how is data supposed to be displayed without function call.

and i do suggest making separate functions for writing and reading from async storage, it will help you reduce your code and time.

Like this:

```
let  storeData=(name, obj)=> {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

            let jsonOfItem = JSON.stringify(obj)
            AsyncStorage.setItem(name, jsonOfItem).then(r=>resolve(jsonOfItem))
            .catch(e=>reject(e))

    })

  }

let  readData=(name)=> {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            //we want to wait for the Promise returned by AsyncStorage.setItem()
            //to be resolved to the actual value before returning the value
            AsyncStorage.getItem(name).then(r=> resolve(JSON.parse(r)) )
            .catch(e=>reject(e))

    })

  }

//Now you can just read write easily in async function like this:

let fetchedData = await  readData("key")

//and for storing data.

storeData("key",object)
```